# Python : Stem TOR Controller: SocketError: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

Tags: python, sockets, google-colaboratory, tor, stem

Hello im having hard time to use the tor stem module, it causes error on the `with Controller.from_port(port=9050) as controller:`I tried to check if my i am running on port 9050 using netstats, the service on the tor is already enabled

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Here's my setup

```
import requests
import socks
import socket
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
session = requests.session()
def renew_tor_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9050) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='malakititeko')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
renew_tor_ip()
```

The traceback error:

```
SOCKS5Error                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socks.py in connect(self, dest_pair, catch_errors)
    808                 negotiate = self._proxy_negotiators[proxy_type]
--> 809                 negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
    810             except socket.error as error:

10 frames
SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GeneralProxyError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SocketError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/stem/socket.py in _make_socket(self)
    536       return control_socket
    537     except socket.error as exc:
--> 538       raise stem.SocketError(exc)
    539 
    540 

SocketError: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you given code change the port to the 9051 and configure the password on the `torrc` found on the `etc/tor/` uncomment the `ControlPort`, password replace that with your own password generated using `tor --hash-pssword <your password>` this should work

Try to explore this repo for more infos:

https://github.com/sksoumik/rotate_IP

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to connect to the Tor controller through the Tor proxy. You should connect to it directly.